# rCharts not displaying and no errors. Just a blank screen

Tags: r, rcharts

I have a graph that I can create with this ggplot2 code:

```
ggplot(total.new, aes(x=day, y=new.total)) + geom_line() + 
      facet_wrap("practice", scales="free_y", ncol=2)
```

Now I wanted to try out rCharts, so I tried the following:

```
rPlot(new.total ~ day | practice, data=total.new, type='line')
```

and all I get is a blank screen in the viewer with no errors of any kind. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: It would help if you provided a `dput(total.new)` so folks cld reproduce your example.

Comment: My gut instinct says it is because of the variable `new.total` which has periods in the name. Javascript interprets periods differently, so just try changing `new.total` to `new_total`.

Comment: No, the dot isn't it. I'm having the same problem with rMaps and the crosslet() function.

Comment: See if you can open in the browser outside of the viewer and then look in the console for any errors that you might be able to provide us for additional clues.